# How to get key and value of a Dictionary in Array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I added some `key`,`value` dictionary to an `array`, now when I'm trying to get all the pairs I got some error:

this is the code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "January")
    {
        Dictionary<string, int>[] temperatures = new Dictionary<string, int>[2];
        temperatures[0]=new Dictionary<string, int>();
        temperatures[1]=new Dictionary<string, int>();
        temperatures[0].Add("Day1",22);
        temperatures[1].Add("Day2",23);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> temperture in temperatures[])
        {
            Label1.Text = string.Format("at {0} the temperture is {1} degree", temperture.Key, temperture.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the error or problem is this line:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> temperture in temperatures[])
```

If I write `temperatures[]` I get the error message:

> syntax error, value expected
>   indexer has 1 parameter(s) but it invoke with 0 argument()

and if I add an index like `temperatures[0]` or `temperatures[1]`, I just get the key and value of first or second items but not all of them.

What should I do?

Comment: Why you store `"Day1"` as key in the dictionary and not simply `1`?

Comment: `KeyValuePair<string,int> temperture in temperatures[]` How does that even work?

Comment: Use Dictionary<string, List<int>>

Comment: @mohsen use this code  `foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> temperture in temperatures)` instead of `foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> temperture in temperatures[])` ... bcz you have to remove `[]` brackets

Comment: I can't remove [] , I face an error again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `temperatures` is an array of dictionaries - you have to explicitly indicate what element of this array you're accessing.

So, if you need to traverse all pairs from all dictionaries in array - just add one more loop:

```
foreach (var t in temperatures)
{
   foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> temperture in t)
   {
        // do whatever yoou need
   }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work , it just show me the second key, value not the first

Comment: @Mohsen if `Label1.Text = string.Format("at {0} the temperture is {1} degree", temperture.Key, temperture.Value);` mentioned in question is your real code and not a syntetic example - then `Label1.Text` will always have text based on very last key-value pair in the last dictionary. You're just overwriting this text each time. Probably your intent was somehow concatenate values from all pairs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten the collection of dictionaries so you can iterate over each `KeyValuePair` in every dictionary:

```
foreach(var temperature in temperatures
    .SelectMany(t => t))
{
    Label1.Text = $"at {temperature.Key} the temperture is {temperature.Value} degree";
}
```

Also note the [interpolated string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx) instead of `String.Format` to make it a little more readable.

Comment: i don't have ".SelectMany"

Comment: Make sure you have added `using System.Linq;`